# Accumulation point proofs

Tags: general-topology

I understand accumulation points are basically limits and how to look at an accumulation point when given a numerical sequence but I'm having trouble finding some way of proving the following two claims and would like some help:

a) Claim: If a set contains each of its accumulation points it must be closed

b) Claim: A finite set of points $z_1,...z_n$ lacks accumulation points.

I really have no idea how to get started or what theorems to use.
${}{}{}{}$

Comment: It is helpful if you include the definition of "closed" that you are working with. In some books, claim (a) *is* the definition of closed. Also, what is the definition of accumulation point in the text you are using?

Answer (score 0):

let $F$ be a set that contains each of its accumulation points.To show $X\setminus F$ is open.Consider $x\in X\setminus F$ then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $F$ .By definition  of accumulation point there must exist an open ball $B(x,r)$ for some $r>0$ having empty intersection with $F$ .Thus $B(x,r)\subset X\setminus F$. Hence $X\setminus F$ is open.

For the second part ;Let $F$ be a finite set in $\mathbb R^2$ and hence closed ,now can you take it from here?